# Mega Menu is in a different state depending on user

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, hub-site, megamenu

I'm using a SharePoint Online Mega Menu on the central hub site. Every time we change the mega menu, our users receive a different version. Every user appears to see a different version of the menu, depending on the time they accessed the menu.

I suspect that the menu is either cached in the browser or in the user's server side data. At the moment I can see the same menu on both Firefox and Chrome, while other users see a different menu.

The last change to the mega menu was changing the title of the "Hotline" / "IT Support" section. This change happened over a week ago. Reloading the tab and emptying the cache does not change the title to the new one.

Here's a screenshot of the menu as I see it right now:
[image: my mega menu screenshot]

Here's a screenshot of the menu as my scrum master sees it right now:
[image: scrum master mega menu screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We encounter the same. What it helps was to go to Site Settings -> Look and Feel and Quick Launch. There delete all the items. It basically vanish all the Mega Menu and Quick Launch itself. So backup what you create there. Now when you create new items, it propagate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, Associated site will inherit the hub site navigation in a short time.

Please refer to the following article to diagnosis page performance:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/page-diagnostics-for-spo

Comment: I'm on the hub site, all associated sites have the same navigation as the hub site. The inheritance is fine. As for the page performance, it's all pretty normal. The page logo is not using a CDN, but other than that, there are no red flags.
I'd guess that the issue is a desync of the hub site's mega menu data somewhere between the client that adjusted the navigation, the server and the user's browser.

Comment: If it's the server issue, I suggest you open a ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: @RubbelDieKatz did you ever work this out? I see the same thing.

Comment: Nope, I simply accepted my fate. Whenever this issue occurs just use a different browser or incognito mode 

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm it worked for me.

I have the same issue with weird working navigation on the site. Some users had different positions.

Here is the clue:

1. Site Settings -> Look and Feel and Quick Launch
2. Remove all the positions and save it empty.
3. Recreate menu from scratch BUT do it from Quick Launch position not on the site ! (somehow it is not working properly)

Two important hints on the side.
A. Paste complete hyperlinks (if you do not have all subsite use main site temporarily). SHarepoint could not display false links with dot for example
B. If position is main item (not sublink) add it as "New Heading" not "New Link". Links could not be promoted on Classic View where we add thoose

Hope this helps.